# SIM800L HTTPSSL with unknown error

Tags: ssl, https, at-command, gprs

My story is, I opened up a new phone with SIM800L which I brought recently and did old http mojo to it. I encountered this problem as

```
AT+HTTPSSL=1
+CME ERROR: 100

at+httpssl=?
+CME ERROR: 100

at+httpssl?
+CME ERROR: 100
```

I guess this command is not existing anymore? Since I had the old phone from two years ago and that one works...

Here is working flow

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
  0
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet"
  0
AT+HTTPINIT
  0
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
  0
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://*****/demo/api/authenticate"
  0
AT+HTTPPARA="REDIR",1
  0
AT+HTTPSCONT
  0
AT+HTTPTERM
  0
AT+SAPBR=1,1
  0
AT+HTTPINIT
  0
AT+HTTPSSL=1
  +CME ERROR: 100
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
  0
AT+HTTPDATA=69,10000
  DOWNLOAD
  {"id":"*****","password":"*************************"}
  0
AT+HTTPACTION=1
  0
+HTTPACTION: 1,603,0
```

The http error 603 indicates I was trying to post to https with http, I guess?

Answer (score -1):

The error 603 means DNS error. See the most common errors table:

- 600 Not HTTP PDU
- 601 Network Error
- 602 No Memory
- 603 DNS Error
- 604 Stack Busy

I hope it helps you.